# Chrome plugin to allow to open file://

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-devtools

From our website, we need to open a local resource via `file://something`. We are getting a security error - at least in Chrome. Is it possible to allow files to be read via a `file://` protocol by writing a Chrome plugin and saving an allowed location there? Any suggestions?

Comment: Chrome *extensions* can access file:// URLs if the user enables the corresponding checkbox on chrome://extensions page and the extension has permissions for `file://*/*` or `<all_urls>`.

Comment: OK, so can we limit it by our domain, something like:  `file://[*.]myurl.com`  ?

Comment: Or, a simpler way - can people set that in their Chrome prefs? Or does it have to be a plugin?

Comment: Extensions can ask interactively for *optional permissions*. I have no idea about plugins, nobody uses them.